# How to orientate pictures minimally on page by rotation/.../two-columns?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, rotating

I can orientate figures like on one column with much white space around by the following code, but I do not like it because the amount of pages gets very big fast

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\extrafloats{1000}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ii in {1,...,62} {
  \IfFileExists{\ii.jpg}{
    \begin{figure}
      \centering% not \center!
      \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{\ii.jpg}
      \caption{Image.} %\ii.}
    \end{figure}
%    \clearpage
  }{}
} % closing brace for loop
\end{document}
```

I think the possible options to get more images on pages would be to consider the *dimensions* of each image and put them side by then. 
Also, the slight rotation of the images is possible by 1-25 degrees which could help in fitting.

I first thought that Tikz could help on this matter but I am not convinced anymore.

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: there are various known algorithms for packing shapes but given the lack of information here I don't see how this can be answered.  Can the figures be re-ordered for example (putting all the small ones together would help), how can rotating a rectangle by 10 degrees help with packing?  the figure environment is adding extra vertical space and introducing the possibility of the whole lot floating neither of which you want so why not just use `\includegraphics` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution depends on which size you want to fix: whether all images should have the same size, or whether their sizes may differ. Basically you can pack each image and its caption into a box and then let TeX distribute the images. Here is an example similar to yours fixing the width to `3.5cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\extrafloats{1000}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\imagewidth{3.5cm}
\noindent
\foreach \ii in {1,...,62} {%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\imagewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
      \captionof{figure}{Image \ii}%
      \bigskip
      \end{minipage}
      \hfill
} % closing brace for loop
\end{document}
```

[image]